# Is there a way to use @import for css files cache savely?

Tags: css, cache-control

I want to knwo if there is a way to use the `@import` command with a parameter that ensures, that the css file is loaded from the server?

I already gave the css file that includes the `@import` command a variable:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/frontend/css/main.css?v=<?=VERSION?>" >
```

In the css file I could only do it hardcoded:

```
@import "include/layout.css?v=123";
@import "include/navigatioin.css?v=123";
```

The whole thing runs on an apache server in php7, if that inforamtion helps.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way you can force a reload in css is by changing the version in the import url as you mentioned in your question.

*Not sure if this helps but*, using php and apache you can use `filemtime()` together with rewrite rules to auto update the version name of the css whenever a change has been made to the file.

Here's an example:

```
// Pass in the url path to the file '/frontend/css/main.css' for example
function css_auto_version($file) {
    // Return $file if the path is faulty to prevent errors.
    if(strpos($file, '/') !== 0 || !file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file))
        return $file;
    
    // filemtime() returns a timestamp showing the last time the file was changed.
    $mtime = filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file);

    // return '/frontend/css/main.TIMESTAMP.css'
    return preg_replace('{\\.([^./]+)$}', ".$mtime.\$1", $file);
}
```

Then in your .htaccess file for the document root you need to add the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css)$ $1.$2 [L]
```

This rewrite rule basically tells apache to look for '/frontend/css/main.TIMESTAMP.css' at '/frontend/css/main.css' instead.

Now you can use this function in your php template like this `echo css_auto_version('/frontend/css/main.css');` and the filename in the path will always include a timestamp of the last time the file was changed.
Any browser with an older version cached will believe it's a completely different file and reload it from the server. The rewrite rule will remove the timestamp in the requests and let the server will find the correct css file and send it back to the browser.

Since you can't use php inside a css file, you will probably have to include the `@import` rules in a `style` tag in the HTML and include the php there.

You can read more about `filemtime` here https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_filemtime.asp

If you really want to just always force a reload, whether or not the file has actually changed, then I'd suggest setting http headers like no-cache in the response. You can read more about that here:

HTTP Cache-control https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

PHP header() https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp

Hope that helps!